# Why is my header not going according to my CSS?

Tags: css

I'm wondering why isn't the size of my header going according to my CSS attribute?
This is how i link my header with my css.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<img src="image/s1.jpg" >
    <ul id="Slideshow">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</ul>
```

and this is my CSS

```
#Slideshow
{
  width: 100%;
  left:0%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0%;
  height:320px;
}
```

as you can see, i have already added width 100%. Unfortunately, the width of my header doesn't even seems to be like 100%. I have also added a left:0%. However, the header didnt exactly go all the way to the left. There's still some empty spaces.

Comment: 100% to what? what is the size of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either set a container width for #SlideShow, or set a fixed width for #slideShow.

try changing your css to the following.

```
#Slideshow
{
  width: 600px;height:320px  
  position: absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
}

#Slideshow img{width:100%;}
```